# How to use vue-router's $route and $router properties with vue-class-component?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vue-class-components

I'm migrating my Vue 2 project from JS to TS with class-based components. In my code, I used `vue-router` by accessing `this.$route` and `this.$router` properties. However, in class-based Typescript components, accessing these properties obviously gives a compile-time error, because they are defined dynamically at runtime by `VueRouter` plugin.

```js
// Something like this works fine in my JS-based Vue components
export default {
  methods: {
    route() {
      return this.$route;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// Compile time error: TS2339: Property '$route' does not exist on type 'RouteUser'.
@Component
export default class RouteUser extends Vue {
    route() {
      return this.$route;
    }
}
```

Then how do I use `vue-router` and `vue-class-component` together?

Comment: Vue 2's Typescript solution is different than Vue 3's. There is no support for class components in Vue 3. Vue 3's router and vuex stores have much better Typescript support and you should not run into issues like this. I would hold off on this work until you are ready to switch to Vue 3 (which was just released) and then you will have an easier time with Typescript conversion.